# How to re-apply already reverted back changes in git

Tags: git

How to re-apply already reverted back changes in git

1. Made some changes to "git push"
2. git revert "2398239" - later
3. Made some changes to "git push"
4. I would like to pullback changes from the revert in [2]

How should I do this?

Comment: You could simply cherry-pick the old commit: `git cherry-pick 2398239`, although reverting the revert as suggested would probably be bit more explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When doing the step 2, you will get a new commit ID. You can revert that commit ID. This is basiclly reverting the revert and same as reverting a comit.

```
Made some changes to "git push" //commit id "2398239"
git revert "2398239" - later // commit id "2345678"
Made some changes to "git push"
git revert "2345678"
```